# Missing method body, or declare abstract in Java

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and tried to get things running on my computer.

A simple "hello world program" fails calling a method

```
class helloworld
{   
    public static void main(String[] param)
    {
        helloWorld();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void helloWorld();
    {
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
.\helloworld.java:11: error: missing method body, or declare abstract
       public static  void helloworld();
                           ^
```

Comment: just a hint: by convention class names begin with capital letter

Comment: If you were using an IDE like eclipse, it will notify you to correct your mistake. However its obvious mistake for writing code in some text editor.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Remove the semicolon on the end of this line: `public static void helloWorld();`

Comment: One reason why I prefer the opening brace on the same line -- a mistake like that becomes quite a bit more obvious.

Comment: @Simon André Forsberg  He is using System.exit(0); Does it make any difference in this program or to JVM?

Comment: @smit It's not really related to this error, but it's an useless call. If omitted, Java will automatically exit with exit status 0.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
public static void helloWorld();
```

is your problem.  Ending a function with a semicolon implies you want it to be abstract and not have a body.  This is similar to how methods in interfaces are declared, or if they are marked abstract i.e. no body.

Answer (score 1):

In this code line:

`public static void helloWorld();`
 remove semicolon.

Make it like this:

`public static void helloWorld()`

To avoid this mistake further on, do it like this:

`public static void helloWorld() {`

An opening curly brace in the same line would make error detection easier.

Answer (score -1):

first you focus on your error.. solution of error is (

```
abstract class HelloWorld
{
public abstract void(String[] args);
```

you shoud try this ;)