# Creating my first class and getting the error "missing method body or declare abstract"

Tags: java, class

I have ran into a error while creating my first class. Unfortunately, the online professor I have only reads the powerpoint and doesn't give much hands on instruction. Anyways, does anyone know why I get the error message on the `public void initialize`? Any help and explanation will be appreciated. Also if there are any links to videos where a class is created besides the simple int=x etc, that would be appreciated!

```
 package csci1010.assign4;

/**
*
* @author George Lucas
*/
public class Ball {
// Private Instance Variables are declared below
private double hDist=0, vDist=0; // Horizontal and vertical distance of ball
private double hSpeed=0, vSpeed=0; //Horizontal and vertical travel of ball

// Public methods to be used
public void initialize (double angle, double velocity, double height);
{
    vDist = height;
    hSpeed = velocity * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle));
    vSpeed = velocity * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle));
}
```

Comment: Please show the full error message

Comment: The linked duplicate has the identical problem, practically the same title and same [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13866968/256196).

Answer (score 3):

provide a close bracket to your class and remove semicolon from initialize

```
/**
 *
 * @author George Lucas
 */
public class Ball {
  // Private Instance Variables are declared below
  private double hDist = 0, vDist = 0; // Horizontal and vertical distance of ball
  private double hSpeed = 0, vSpeed = 0; // Horizontal and vertical travel of ball

  // Public methods to be used
  public void initialize(double angle, double velocity, double height) {
    vDist = height;
    hSpeed = velocity * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle));
    vSpeed = velocity * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle));
  }
}
```

Points to be noted:

1. The class body should be enclosed within the curly braces `{}`
2. Semi-colon represents the end of statement, since initialize is just a beginning of method body, so we should not keep any semi-colon after initialize.

For a very basic tutorial, there are lot of free available sites and mock-ups. Just follow those thoroughly. Good contents can be found in:

> Pluralsight, Udacity, Udemy

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I overlooked that. What does the semicolon cause the program to interpret?

Comment: semicolon ```'``` means the end of statement in java.

Comment: Ah yes that's right. Therefore the information after would not be connected. Simple mistakes

Comment: That naughty semicolon was making the compiler think perhaps you were trying to define an [abstract method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) -- a method without a body. But in order to do that, you would need to use the `abstract` keyword, like: `public abstract void foo();` and your class would also need to be defined as abstract, like `public abstract class Foo`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. We haven't gotten that far yet. This makes more sense and allows me to understand the error message better.